# Unable to initialize threads vector

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency

I have implemented this simple [C++11 Blocking Queue](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/128832/c11-blocking-queue-learning-exercise) that I'd like to test. In order to test it, I initialize the following producer and consumer thread vectors with 10 producers and 10 consumers respectively.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

#include "blockingqueue.h"

int main() {
    // create a blocking queue with capacity 3
    blocking_queue<int> queue(3);

    uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 10);
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 gen(rd());

    // create 10 producers
    vector<thread> producers(10, thread([&] () {
        cout << "attempting to produce a job ..." << endl;
        int job = dis(gen);
        queue.put(job);
        cout << "produced job " << job << endl;
    }));

    // create 10 consumers
    vector<thread> consumers(10, thread([&] () {
        cout << "attempting to take a job ..." << endl;
        int job = queue.take();
        cout << "consumed job " << job << endl;
    }));

    // wait for all producers to complete
    for(auto& thread : producers){
        thread.join();
    }

    // wait for all consumers to complete
    for(auto& thread : consumers){
        thread.join();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However, I can't get it to compile with the following errors:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF"src/cpp11showcase.d" -MT"src/cpp11showcase.o" -o "src/cpp11showcase.o" "../src/cpp11showcase.cpp"
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/vector:62:0,
                 from ../src/cpp11showcase.cpp:13:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = std::thread; _Args = {const std::thread&}]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:187:48:   required from ‘static void std::__uninitialized_fill_n<_TrivialValueType>::__uninit_fill_n(_ForwardIterator, _Size, const _Tp&) [with _ForwardIterator = std::thread*; _Size = long unsigned int; _Tp = std::thread; bool _TrivialValueType = false]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:224:35:   required from ‘void std::uninitialized_fill_n(_ForwardIterator, _Size, const _Tp&) [with _ForwardIterator = std::thread*; _Size = long unsigned int; _Tp = std::thread]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:334:50:   required from ‘void std::__uninitialized_fill_n_a(_ForwardIterator, _Size, const _Tp&, std::allocator<_Tp2>&) [with _ForwardIterator = std::thread*; _Size = long unsigned int; _Tp = std::thread; _Tp2 = std::thread]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:1215:32:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_fill_initialize(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type, const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::thread; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::thread>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::thread]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:284:40:   required from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type, const value_type&, const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = std::thread; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::thread>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::thread; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<std::thread>]’
../src/cpp11showcase.cpp:83:4:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::thread::thread(const std::thread&)’
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
       ^
In file included from ../src/blockingqueue.h:13:0,
                 from ../src/cpp11showcase.cpp:18:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:126:5: error: declared here
     thread(const thread&) = delete;
     ^
make: *** [src/cpp11showcase.o] Error 1
```

UPDATE: it seems that the vector initialization doesn't like to capture the referenced variables by reference i.e. queue, dis and gen. The thread copy constructor has the method `thread(const thread&) = delete;` unavailable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// create 10 producers
vector<thread> producers(10, thread([&] () {
    cout << "attempting to produce a job ..." << endl;
    int job = dis(gen);
    queue.put(job);
    cout << "produced job " << job << endl;
}));
```

The constructor of [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) will copy the [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) 10 times, but you can't copy a `std::thread`, because its copy constructor is deleted.

Instead, you can use [`std::vector::emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back):

```
vector<thread> producers;
//Loop 10 times (for 10 threads)
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    produces.emplace_back([&] () {
        cout << "attempting to take a job ..." << endl;
        int job = queue.take();
        cout << "consumed job " << job << endl;
    });
```

---

I don't think there is a way to construct `n` elements in place in a `std::vector`, but you could put the loop in a function:

```
template<typename T>
void fillThread(std::vector<std::thread>& threads, std::size_t count, T func)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        threads.emplace_back(func);
}
```

You can then call it like so:

```
std::vector<std::thread> producers;

fillThread(producers, 10, [&] () {
        cout << "attempting to take a job ..." << endl;
        int job = queue.take();
        cout << "consumed job " << job << endl;
    });
```

Comment: Nice answer! thank you! However, I would be happier to have a more direct initialization than going through a loop. Is there a more elegant way to solve this use-case and avoid the loop???

Comment: @GiovanniAzua You could try `std::generate` with a `std::back_inserter` or something similar.

Comment: @Angew I don't think that would work though, because `std::generate` assigns the values with `operator=`

Comment: @GiovanniAzua I'll continue to look, but I currently didn't find one without loop

Comment: @Angew but `std::generate` doesn't move them, it copies them

Comment: @Rakete1111 Why would it copy? The generator produces an r-value. [See here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3aa32e1aa402ded5).

Comment: @Angew Doesn't mean that it will move them, just that it **can**, but it doesn't.

Comment: @Rakete1111 *Not* moving there would require specific code to prevent the move. Why would anyone put it there? See the live example in my previous comment.

Comment: @Rakete1111 But in your example, the generator returns a lambda, and not `std::thread`. It's therefore trying to move-assign a closure into a `std::thread` object, which is not allowed. You can create a `std::thread` with an invokable, but not assign one into it.